# how (in maya) can i get the 3D position of the mouse?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d, maya, autodesk

i have created a dragger context in maya using the following code, pos holds my 2D coordinates of mouse cursor, i want to convert it into 3D coordinate to be the source of the ray i want to launch,, i want it either through python scripting or through the python api,,

```
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.draggerContext( 'testContext', pressCommand='getCursorPos()',
                    dragCommand='getCursorPos()', cursor='default')

def getCursorPos():

    #--get the 2D position of cursor (on the view port)----

    pos = mc.draggerContext( 'testContext', query=1, dragPoint=1) 

    #----convert to 3D coordinates in the scene--------
    ????????
```

thanks in advance

Comment: # Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 4:  #

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you might wanna look into the **space(sp)** flag in the **draggerContext** command help.

```
mc.draggerContext('sampleContext', dragCommand='getCursorPos()', space='world')

def getCursorPos():
    print mc.draggerContext( 'testContext', query=1, dragPoint=1)
```

...should print you the worldspace XYZ values of the click.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the projection (-pr) options for the draggerContext?

Mouse co-ordinates is data across 2 dimensions, and the projection options are methods to resolve how the 3rd dimension is mapped.  For rays, maybe one of the following options is relevant to your question:

xAxis   project to closest point on X axis
yAxis   project to closest point on Y axis
zAxis   project to closest point on Z axis

Here's hoping that helps and best of luck.